# Error : there is no parameter $1postgres sql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to insert data into table using below query. But it's working fine without parametrization but when I add parameter to query. It throws error there is no parameter $1.
Using nodejs to execute query.

```
INSERT INTO or(
              json,id,ortatus,status,
              qty,initial_qty,name,position,pled,
              price,value,created_by,created_on,modified_on)
            SELECT  
              $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$8,$10,$11,'0000000000',to_timestamp('${timestamp}'),
              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM OR WHERE ID=$12) 
              ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`,[`${Json}`,Id,orStatus,Status,
              qty,initialQty,`${name}`,Position,pled,Price,Value,Id])
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nodeJs

Comment: That query makes no sense. What is the actual error message returned? What is the query that works?